# How do you represent money in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'd say I prefer decimals so according to [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) I'm told "Note: When dealing with currency, it is a best practice to have a currency class that serializes to and from an int or use the Decimal form." Not sure what that means.

Also, does decimal in the column as a data type allow for negative values (as in overdraft)? And what is the computational difference between bigint and say decimal and the memory load difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decimal` in CQL is `BigDecimal` in Java (here is [table with mapping of CQL types in Java types by Java driver 3.x](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)). `BigDecimal` is signed, so you can specify the negative values as well.  The main "problem" with decimals is that you can't exactly reason about how much space it will use. And sometimes there could be harder to work with these values from some programming languages...

`bigint` is on other side just a Java `long`, that has predictable size (8 bytes), and available in all programming languages.  You can use it, or `int` to represent money in cents, or something like.  The comment in docs most probably refers to a possibility of [defining a custom codec](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/) that is available in some languages, such as Java, where you can define a custom class for money, and add a codec that will convert it to/from bigint/int.